# Windows 10 upgrade lost brightness Sony VAIO laptop

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

Following an upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 7 on my Sony VAIO laptop, I have lost the ability to brighten the screen although controls indicate full brightness.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please note that Sony has recommended no one using a Vaio PC update to Windows 10 (see [here](https://esupport.sony.com/p/os10upgrade.pl?prods/VPCF226FM/)). The very reason is that their drivers may not work at all for many / any devices. But don't worry, latest rumor is people will have Their drivers ready in October (for people with Windows 8.1 originally pre-installed), November (for people with W8 originally installed), or...? for those with W7 pre-installed...like me...

Answer (score 5):

I had to edit the registry key **Feature Test Control** in

> HKEY LOCAL
>   MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000
>   (or 0001)

I set the value of `FeatureTestControl` to 0x0000fb20 (64288). Screen brightness works fine now.

Comment: I had to reject an edit made by an anonymous user. The suggested edit was: _well, this didn't work for me_

Comment: Yeah, this is the real solution for this problem. I had the same problem on Windows 8 upgrade, but had forgot about the solution. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Rejected edit from [Maria Alice Maia](http://superuser.com/users/510825/maria-alice-maia) - added it as a comment, instead: "Great! This worked for me as well, but I had to do an extra step after editing it!

Finally, I checked at Display Adapter on Device Manager, It showed as enable. Then I disabled it and enabled again.

Screen brightness works fine now. The same as before the Win 10 Update."

Comment: I had the same problem on an Asus Zenbook and this solution worked!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to disabling "enable adaptive brightness" under advanced power settings in Control Panel you must also:

1. Launch VAIO Control Center (<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> then type in **VAIO control center**)
2. Under *Display* uncheck **adjust brightness settings automatically**

Comment: Worked for me, though had to reboot.

Comment: It took a very long while before the Vaio control center actually displayed the checkbox in the "adjust brightness settings automatically" sub menu. The control center also hangs most time, probably buggy under Win10.

Comment: Did not solve the problem - the internal screen still is dark.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to reinstall the drivers specific to the VAIO that deal with the buttons/key presses specific to that model. Often Windows will not contain the vendor specific software required for some features found on that same vendors hardware.

As a concrete example, I have an HP NC4200. If I install a fresh copy of Windows 7 on it, then none of the Sound/Brightness/SD Card slots/Touchscreen/Video functions work "out of the box", and it is necessary to visit the HP website, look up my particular model and then download all of the drivers required. In my case, there were over *ten* addition separate drivers required.

So, I would advise you to visit the Sony website and look up  your VAIO model and find the relevant drivers.

NOTE: It is possible that as Windows 10 is very new, Sony may not have updated their drivers yet. You could try reinstalling the Windows 7 drivers again, they *may* work. Or you may have to wait until a Windows 10 compatible set of drivers becomes available.

---

Another answer was *added as an edit* to my answer, by an anonymous user, which I have made a separate community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

It happened on my friend's Vaio laptop but I managed to fix it by setting the auto-brightness setting to OFF. It seems that the Windows 10 update made the setting on a Vaio laptop revert back to default. So you need to turn auto-brightness off via your Vaio setting.